# Dreamweaver CS5 - Error lines under CSS code

Tags: css, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I have these squiggly lines under CSS code that isn't cross browser compatible. It's really bugging me. Anyone know how to turn it off?

[image: Dreamweaver CS5 - Lines under code]

Thanks in advance for anyone sharing ideas on how to remove!

Comment: That's odd. Your `border-color: #f0f0f0 transparent;` is perfectly valid *and* compatible across browsers; it's not supposed to error out on that line.

Comment: yea im fiddling around with settings now if i fix the issue i'll let you know! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Internet Explorer for Windows versions up to and including 6 do not support `transparent` borders.

Source: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-color

Assuming you're not developing for IE6, you should can choose to [ignore this issue from the compatibility check](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSA994C0FE-60C8-456d-8EF9-EC09DF0FD914a.html#WSE8391D53-06F7-4a1f-9B0E-3AF15D076E4Ba) and carry on.

Comment: Ah yes, not sure how I could *totally* have missed that... ;)